# Task function must be specified with GULP in AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I need to use gulp(using version4), which I need for compile an old project, but running "gulp serve" giving the error:

```
   gulp serve
assert.js:383
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION] [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\User\choosy-front\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (C:\Users\User\choosy-front\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\choosy-front\gulp-tasks\env\dev\tasks.js:29:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1139:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1159:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1028:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\choosy-front\gulpfile.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1139:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1159:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:988:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1028:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at execute (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js:36:18)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js:206:24)
    at Liftoff.execute (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:201:12)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\flagged-respawn\index.js:51:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:191:5)
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:149:9
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\v8flags\index.js:138:14
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\v8flags\index.js:41:14
    at C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\v8flags\index.js:53:7
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
 {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
```

I don't have any tasks, the gulpfile.js content:

```
   'use strict';
// "dist" tasks and build processes.
require('./gulp-tasks/dist/tasks.js');
require('./gulp-tasks/dist/build.js');

// "dev" environment tasks & builds processes.
require('./gulp-tasks/env/dev/tasks.js');
require('./gulp-tasks/env/dev/build.js');

// "stage" environment tasks & builds processes.
require('./gulp-tasks/env/stage/tasks.js');
require('./gulp-tasks/env/stage/build.js');

// "stage" environment tasks & builds processes.
require('./gulp-tasks/env/production/tasks.js');
require('./gulp-tasks/env/production/build.js');
```

when I tried version 3 I got the error:

```
ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:33:5
    at req_ (C:\Users\User\choosy-front\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (C:\Users\User\choosy-front\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\choosy-front\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
```

what should I  do so I can run the server?
I don't think that the problem is with the undertaker module no?
Thank you

Comment: What do you have in your terminal if you write gulp --version ?

Comment: @JérômeW CLI version: 2.2.1
Local version: 4.0.2

Comment: @JérômeW I edited the post

Comment: I don't undersstand your gulpfile, you don't have any task. Your error is `Task function must be specified`. Why you don't add a task ?

Comment: did you try to add all your tasks in the same gulpfile without the requires ?

Comment: This is a common error.  But you'll have to show us your file with the `serve` task in it for us to help.

Comment: Edit your question to show this file `gulp-tasks\env\dev\tasks.js`.